# displaying fetched mysql data using an external css

Tags: php, mysql, css, phpmyadmin

How can I attach an external CSS file to display data fetched from a MySQL database? Can I display data using CSS instead of using tables. I want to completely avoid tables in diplaying the fetched data.

This is the code to fetch data from the MySQL database:

```
<?php
echo "Database Date: " .date("Y-m-d");
?>
```

Variables included in this data are: Assigned NCL Number, Hospital, Age, Sex, Primary cancer and the date of diagnosis and latest management on the patient.

```
<style type="text/css">
  table.data { width:100%;  margin: 0;
      border: 1px solid black; border-spacing: 2px; }
  .id {width: 7%; background-color: #c7c7c0; }
  .date {width: 12%; background-color: #d8d8d1; }
  .nclnumber { width: 10%; background-color: #c7c7c0; }
  .hospital {width: 17%; background-color: #d8d8d1; }
  .age { width: 3%; background-color: #c7c7c0; }
  .sex { width: 2%; background-color: #d8d8d1; }
  .cancer { width: 10%; background-color: #d8d8d1; }
  .dateofdiagnosis { width: 7%; background-color: #d8d8d1; }
  .notes { width: 32%; background-color: #d8d8d1; }  
</style> 

<table class="data" border="0" cellspacing="2">
  <tr>
    <td class="id"><b>Id</b></td>
    <td class="date"><b>Date</b></td>
    <td class="nclnumber"><b>NCL Number</b></td>
    <td class="hospital"><b>Hospital</b></td>
    <td class="age"><b>Age</b></td>
    <td class="sex"><b>Sex</b></td>
    <td class="cancer"><b>Diagnosed Cancer</b></td>
    <td class="dateofdiagnosis"><b>Date of Diagnosis</b></td>
    <td class="notes"><b>Notes</b></td>
   </tr>
 </table>


<?php
// Connects to your Database 
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("cancer") or die(mysql_error()); 
 $data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM cancer WHERE Age ='1'OR Age = '2' OR Age = '3'OR Age = '4'OR Age = '5'OR Age = '6'OR Age = '7'OR Age = '8'OR Age = '9'")  
 or die(mysql_error()); 


while($info = mysql_fetch_array( $data )) {
  echo "<table class='data' border='0' cellspacing='2'>
          <tr>
            <td class='id'>".$info['Id']."</td>
            <td class='date'>".$info['Date']."</td>
            <td class='nclnumber'>".$info['NCL_Number']."</td>
            <td class='hospital'>".$info['Hospital']."</td>
            <td class='age'>".$info['Age']."</td>
            <td class='sex'>".$info['Sex']."</td>
            <td class='cancer'>".$info['Diagnosed_Cancer']."</td>
            <td class='dateofdiagnosis'>".$info['Date_of_Diagnosis']."</td>
            <td class='notes'>".$info['Notes']."</td>
          </tr>
        </table>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Is the data _tabular_? If it is, why avoid tables?  `<table>` tags are not universally evil and replaceable by CSS, they just aren't appropriate for layout.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you pick PDO [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Answer (score 6):

There is absolutely no reason not to use `<table>` elements for tabular data.

The anti-table hysteria that some people have is simply a misunderstanding: it's bad to misuse tables *for layouting purposes*. There's nothing wrong with the HTML tag, though. In fact, using any other HTML element to display tabular data is bad for semantics.

The `<table>` tag and its contained `<tr>` rows and `<td>` columns informs the browser rendering it that the data therein is related and columnar. Don't think of the `<table>` (or any HTML tag for that matter) as strictly a visual display element. They convey meaning about the data to the machine which is parsing it.

Answer (score 1):

Let's sort out a little confusion. Displaying in `CSS` instead of `tables` doesn't make since as `tables` and its associated tags are HTML elements and `CSS` is styling you can apply to those elements. They are not equivalent.

The alternative to tables would be to create a complex, complicated and convoluted layout using a combinations of `divs` and `spans`.

However, there is absolutely no reason why, if the data is tabular, that you should bother with such an awkward design just to avoid the use of the `<table>` tag. That's why the `<table>` tag is in the HTML spec.

Abusing the `<table>` tag for layout purposes has given the tag a bad rep. When used properly though (i.e. to display tabular data) it can be very very useful.

Best advice: use the `<table>` tag and follow the advice of the community wiki.